# A committee of m members is to be chosen from a population of n students. What is your probability of being chosen?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

*A committee of $m$ students is being formed by randomly selecting from a population of n undergraduate students in an engineering college (note: m < n). Assume that you are also included in this population of students. What is the probability that you will be among the $m$ selected students?*

Since you're choosing $m$ amount of students to be in a committee from a population $n$, then the probability of any student being in the committee is $\left(\frac{m}n \right)$. But the probability of you being chosen is $\left(\frac{1}m \right)$. Since the students being selected are not replaced, I used the following equation:

$$
\frac{\left(\frac{1}m \right) \left(\frac{m-1}n \right)}{\left(\frac{m}n \right)}
$$

I feel like I am misunderstanding how permutations are used in this situation, so any insights on how to solve this question would be appreciated.

Comment: There are $\binom{n}{m}$ different committees that can be formed.  There are $\binom{n-1}{m}$ committees that can be formed that don't include you and $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ committees that can be formed that *do* include you.  (*Recall that $\binom{n-1}{m-1}+\binom{n-1}{m}=\binom{n}{m}$ by Pascal's Identity*).  The probability then of the committee including you is $\dfrac{\binom{n-1}{m-1}}{\binom{n}{m}}$ which simplifies to $\dfrac{m}{n}$.

Comment: You even mention that you believed (*though seem as though you couldn't explain why*) that the probability that any particular student being in the committee is $\dfrac{m}{n}$.  This of course should apply to you as well.  You continue on to say "*but the probability of you being chosen is $\frac{1}{m}$*"... This is not the probability you are after.  $\frac{1}{m}$ would be the probability that if we pick one member from the committee at random that you are that person picked *given* that you are known to be one of the committee members.  That is not the problem being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person is fixed in the committee, it must select $m-1$ from $n-1$ people, that is $\dbinom{n-1}{m-1}$

The number of all cases, selecting $m$ people from $n$ is $\dbinom{n}{m}$

$P=\dfrac {\dbinom{n-1}{m-1}}{\dbinom{n}{m}}=\dfrac{m}{n}$